# Join two tables but set precedent for one column value over another

Tags: sql-server

Imagine an HR system and an employee evaluation system. Employees all get one evaluation, but the employees work for potentially two different HR's. I would like to join the two together but only get one row of employee evaluation and HR record. The problem is you will get two rows for any employee in both systems. Is it possible to set a precedence of one value over another? If an employee works in one system, than obviously we will need to use that system. But if they work in

```
create table #eval (
    employeeid int,
    score int
)
insert into #eval
values
(1,5),
(2,3),
(3,4),
(4,4)

create table #hr (
    employeeid int,
    sourcesystem int
)
insert into #hr
values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(3,2),
(4,3)
```

Joining on `employeeid` fails this criteria, but I would like `sourcesystem = 1` over `sourcesystem = 2` or `sourcesystem = 3` when a conflict occurs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MIN if you want source 1 as the result otherwise MAX if you want source 3 or anything higher

```
select 
e.employeeid,
min(h.sourcesystem) minsourcesystem
 from #eval e
inner join #hr h
on e.employeeid = h.employeeid
group by e.employeeid



employeeid  minsourcesystem
----------- ---------------
1           1
2           1
3           2
4           3
```